# Finding selected option in HTML page

Tags: python

How do I find the selected option in HTML page using python?

e.g. in the following example, how do I find the "BOB" string?

```
<select id="worker" name="worker">
<option value="Eve">EVE</option>
<option value="Bob" selected>BOB</option>
<option value="Alice">ALICE</option>
</select>
```

Comment: when using what? You have a webapp and you need to know what has been submitted, or you want to parse a page?

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you are inside a python script and have all your HTML document inside a variable `html`. Most straightforward way would be like this:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
dom = parseString(html)
for element in dom.getElementsByTagName('option'):
    if element.getAttribute('selected'):
       # process selected element
```

But your particular html is not well-formed (hanging `selected` attribute), and will fail to parse by this snippet :(

And I'm afraid you do not want to parse html document, but to process form submission results :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one off job or if all your XML text follow this same format you
could use regexes like so:

```
import re
text = yourtext
matches = re.findall(r'\bselected>([\w]+)<', text,re.MULTILINE )
matches[0] #should return 'Bob'
```

It would be better to change your text to proper XML and then parse it
as @spacediver suggested, especially if you want to get the data reliably
since using regexes is susceptible to breaking easily in case of changes
to the data.